# What database user permissions are needed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, ddl

FYI: SQL Server 2005

I have a database user account (user_web) that has the ability to connect to and run queries and stored procedures in my database. Specifically, I have given the user the `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles as well as granted them execute permission on the specific stored procedures it needs to be able to run.

In one of the stored procedures, I need to disable a trigger then re-enable it after some specific edits are done. When I attempt to run that stored procedure with the user I get the following error:

```
Cannot find the object "TableName" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

`TableName` is the table where I am attempting to disable and enable the trigger. My question is what is the least amount of permissions I can give to my user account that will allow it to successfully run the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user will "at a minimum" require `ALTER` permissions on the table in question. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182706.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Rather than grant the user `ALTER` permissions on the table, which could be a security issue, I'd have that particular stored procedure run as a different user that does have those permissions.  Use the `EXECUTE AS` syntax to accomplish this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx

Comment: He could also look into using a certificate on the stored procedure, although I think that's only necessary if there is an ownership chaining issue(?)  If security were critical though, the blanket db_datareader and db_datawriter probably shouldn't be used.

Comment: I agree with Tom about the db_datareader and db_datawriter.  I'm not a big fan of certificates 'cause I think they're a pain, especially when stuff is still under active development.